# gaierror - [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: django, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, xhtml2pdf

I created a Ubuntu instance with AWS EC2 where I run two docker containers: One to django (python) and another to postgreSQL. The python image contain a dependencie called [xhtml2pdf](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate a PDF starting a HTML. Later of call a lot of petitions to generate a lot PDFs with this dependencie, occurred a the following error when I want generate pdf from URL

`http://XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/presupuestos/1/generar_pdf/`

`gaierror at /presupuestos/1/generar_pdf/
[Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

[image]

This is my views.py where I created a function to generate PDF with xhtml2pdf

```txt
def generar_pdf(request, id):
    data = {}
    data['data'] = get_object_or_404(Presupuesto, id=id)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('presupuestos/html2pdf.html', data) 
    if pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "presupuesto-%s.pdf" % (data['data'].rut_paciente)
        content = "inline; filename='%s'" % (filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        return response
    return HttpResponse("Not Found")
```

urls.py

```txt
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = "presupuestos"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.presupuestos_listado, name='presupuestos_listado'),
    path('buscar_paciente/', views.buscar_paciente, name='buscar_paciente'),
    path('listado_pacientes/', views.listado_pacientes, name='listado_pacientes'),
    path('generar_presupuesto/', views.generar_presupuesto, name='generar_presupuesto'),
    path('<int:id>/generar_pdf/', views.generar_pdf, name='generar_pdf'),
    path('desplegar_informacion/', views.desplegar_informacion, name='desplegar_informacion'),
    path('<int:id>/detalle_presupuesto/', views.detalle_presupuesto, name='detalle_presupuesto'),
]
```

The same is happened in my development environment (Centos 7) where I run the same two containers with docker.
I tried with delete my containers and start it again, but not works. Also I tried with delete the images and containers together, but it does not work either...
To be honest, I dont know what is the issue. I search a lot in internet but I cant found the solution. Can someone help me please!?

**UPDATE 2**

For any reason, today, after a couple of hours I can create PDFs again ... The only what I did was that I said in my above body question (delete image and containers) but it does not work. Like I said, couple of hours after it 
it worked again from nothing... Some idea why it was happened? It could happened again ?

Comment: sounds like you may have an issue with your host or base paths. Check out this link to see if adding some extra configuration would help: https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/doc/source/usage.rst#using-xhtml2pdf-in-django

Comment: thanks @pacuna for your response! :D I tried with the command `xhtml2pdf ./proyecto/templates/presupuestos/html2pdf.html` assuming that this function works with everything but the issue still :/
`socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution`

Comment: Hi @pacuna ! I updated my question. For any reason I can create PDFs again. Any idea why it was happened?

Comment: did you restart or rebuild your images? Sometimes some changes aren't applied unless the images are rebuilt

Comment: Yep, I tried to delete my containers and create again, also I tried with delete containers and images and start from zero but neither works :(